# How to create a UI to run my automation test scripts

Tags: java, user-interface, automation

I have a quick question here, I have a lot of automation test scripts for my application.

To execute all the scripts one after the other i used a test suite.

And i could able to see that some of the scripts are failing, then to execute the failed test cases every time i need to comment the remaining test scripts to run the failed one.

To avoid the above situation i just wanted to create an UI to run my test scripts selectively.

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Before embarking on creating an UI, you might want to take a look at frameworks designed just for the need you seem to be having, like [TestNG](http://testng.org) or [jUnit](http://junit.org) or other.

Comment: You can integrate with jenkins and configure the job to run selected test scripts. or you can create single page application with option to run the scripts.

Comment: Actually i am a Tester so i don't know how to create an UI, and the framework which i am using is JUNIT @toby speight

Comment: @DebanjanB I guess he wants a GUI in which his test units are listed and can be chosen one by one to be executed, or something like that.

Comment: But how can a question `Create a UI` have a `Selenium` tag? Tags should be `Java` , `Python` , `HTML`, etc

Comment: @DebanjanB That's actually unclear, as is what kind of help he is asking for, but my guess is that those are jUnit tests that use Selenium to test web pages, so they fail f.ex. when a certain DOM element is not found, or when the test clicks something and doesn't see the expected effect, things like these.

Comment: Ofcoarse _Test Script_ for _Application A_ will fail when executed against _Application B_ .  Shouldn't script for _Application B_ be written from scratch?